# How to use padding/margin to move a div?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Easy question for CSS Masters

I created two squares using div sections. The first one is a black one and inside it is a red one. The thing is every time I want to move the red square down the black square, the black square goes down with it. How can I stop this?

```
<div class="black">
  <div class="red">

  </div>
<div>


.black{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
}
```

I don't want the black square to go down. How do I stop this?

```
.red{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add position:absolute for both divs and after set left,top as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `.black`'s position to `absolute`.

```
.black {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[See the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sVRHq/)

> **property value: absolute**
>
> The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not
>   static) ancestor element
>
> [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to set it as an absolute element. Since your red box is inside of the black box, **you can use padding** to justify the red box within it.

```
.black {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background: black;
   padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle for it!](http://jsfiddle.net/f5zG3/)

Answer (score 1):

Set the absolute position of black div

```
 position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position of black to relative and position of red to absolute like this:

```
.black{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}
.red{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

Check out [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLXM4/1/)